# Получение данных координат(широта/долгота) по списку адресов

Tags: javascript, html, база-данных

помогите новичку пожалуйста:) мне необходимо по списку адресов в excel-таблице получить соответствующие координаты(широта/долгота) по каждому адресу. Для этого получил бесплатный/пробный ключ для JavaScript API и HTTP Геокодер, на сайте яндекс карты. Подскажите пожалуйста как использовать данный ключ и как бы мне решить в целом описанное выше задание?
Приложу скрин как это должно выглядеть, буду благодарен за любые ссылки где/как такое в принципе делается. Спасиб[image: введите сюда описание изображения]о!

Comment: В [документации](https://yandex.ru/dev/geocode/doc/ru/quickstart) есть примеры... [Формат запроса](https://yandex.ru/dev/geocode/doc/ru/request), [формат ответа](https://yandex.ru/dev/geocode/doc/ru/response) и [примеры использования](https://yandex.ru/dev/geocode/doc/ru/examples).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, как я понял, нужно будет делать запросы на, в моем случае, прямое геокодирование, запрос должен содержать адрес и api ключ и тд., только, как можно будет задать туда весь список адресов(их около 1000), т.е. все это нужно чтобы получать координаты не вбивая адреса по одному в картах. Как бы найти пример реализации подобной задачи.

Comment: [Создайте свою функцию](https://trumpexcel.com/user-defined-function-vba) в Excel на VBA. Примеры использования HTTP запросов рассматриваются [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817602/gethttp-with-excel-vba) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59284862/3129992). Либо, как вариант, выгружать таблицу в файл, обрабатывать, заново загружать в Excel.